# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, getaddrinfo

I had a perfectly running nodejs server on an EC2 instance of Amazon AWS. By mistake, I missed a couple of payments and the service was halted. When I paid and brought the account up to date, I found the server was back in place and was already running.

However, since then, my very first request has started returning the "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error and am not able to check any other request either. This is weird, since the first line in the code to check the health of the server (refer to index.html below) return the desired "All Ok" result. But the subsequent requests gives the ENOTFOUND error. Any help in this will be very much appreciated.

FYI, I have tried stopping and restarting the server, didn't help.

Here is the code of the base file:

```
    require('newrelic');
    var express = require('express'),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        oauthserver = require('oauth2-server');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({ dest: '../uploads/' });
    var controllernew = require('./controllers/controllernew');


    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

/***************************************************************
********FOLLOWING REQUEST RETURNS ALL OK AS DESIRED*************
****************************************************************/
    app.get('/index.html', controllernew.index);

    app.oauth = oauthserver({
        model: require('./models/modeloauth'),
        grants: ['password'],
        debug: true,
        accessTokenLifetime: 31536000
    });

/******************************************************************
*******GETTING ENOTFOUND ERROR FOR THE FOLLOWING REQUEST***********
*******************************************************************/
    app.get('/userOTP/:userid/username/:username', controllernew.getUserOTP);

    app.all('/oauth/token', app.oauth.grant());
    app.all('*', app.oauth.authorise());

    app.use(app.oauth.errorHandler());

    app.post('/uploadimagenew', upload.single('upload'), function(req, res) {
        var controllernew = require('./controllers/controllernew');
        controllernew.createImage2(req, res, function(){
            console.log(req.file);
            console.log(req.body.csvlistevents);
            var strArray = req.body.csvlistevents.split("|");
            console.log(strArray[3]);
        })
    });

    routes = require("./routes/items")();
    app.use(routes);
    var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
        console.log('server started at ' + server.address().port);
    });
```

Comment: It's a DNS issue. Make sure that your server can find whatever host it's looking up - are the DNS records for the hostname set up correctly?

Comment: Kryten, thanks for your comment, though I am not sure how to check that. The public IP of my EC2 is, say 54.xxx.xx.xx. When I hit 54.xxx.xx.xx/index.html, I get the 'All ok' response. But when I hit the 54.xxx.xx.xx/userOTP..... link I get the said error. The server is not looking up any host. Whose DNS record should I check? Could it be while connecting to my RDS instance? index.html doesn't connect to RDS and thus might be working fine.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the issue is - I thought you were indicating that you got that error on the server side; ie. your app was connecting to another resource & returning that error. Are you getting that error in your browser? If that's the case, then I don't know what's going on - I suspect that your server configuration got messed up with Amazon due to the missed payments/account suspension. You should probably take this up with their tech support.